# Navigate a file containing ^J in Vim

Tags: python, vim, file-io

I'm writing to a txt file from python. Whenever I specify a \n write in the python file, I find a ^J in the txt file - when opened using Vi. If I open using any other text editor, I see a clean new line. The standard j and k commands don't work when trying to navigate the txt file. Any solutions?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: windows, linux or other environment?

Comment: and what does you python-line looks like that write the line to file? Perhaps add a `strip()` to remove any wonky line-termination prior to writing

Comment: ^J is linefeed, the standard newline character in Unix. Is your .vimrc set to act as though it's in a Windows-only environment?

Comment: Its Ubuntu installed on a white macbook (2007)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m6upacgw Vimrc, if that helps.

Comment: start vim with `vim -u NONE` to skip reading from your `.vimrc` and it would be nice to see the python-part where you write to file as well. BTW your .vimrc looks ok at a first glance

Comment: ...and if you do `hexdump -C file.txt | sed '10q'` or similar, what does the hexcode for the line-termination shows? It should be a plain `0a`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior in a small case. The actual code where this is happening is part of a large simulation. Here's the section of the code: http://pastebin.com/kzVXKb6s

Comment: You don't have any goofy data in `probabilities`? And what does `hexdump` tell you what the line-endings actually are?

Comment: Here's the output of hexdump: http://pastebin.com/t1YiUwEa. The probabilities data is valid, if I open using another text editor, everything is as expected.

Comment: In the hexdump I don't see any line-terminators such as 0x0A for `\n` or 0x0D for `\r`. You need to paste more data (or just valid data) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is probably detecting the file as a Mac Classic file. I get the same behavior by setting my vim to Mac Classic newline mode. First, open vim and check the value of `ffs`

```
:set ffs?
```

If you see 'mac' anywhere in that line, that's your problem. To see which vim script set that option, run

```
:verbose set ffs?
```

One solution is to set `ffs` manually in your .vimrc

```
set ffs=unix
```

Comment: I set ffs=unix manually in my vimrc, and it still shows fileformats=unix,mac. As far as the source, its due to a plugin called sensible. Does this mean the plugin overrides the vimrc?

Comment: Have you tried starting vim with `vim -u NONE` to disable any setup?

Comment: `unix,dos,mac` or `unix,mac` should work fine; It tries `unix` and `dos` first, and uses `mac` only if no `\n` or `\r\n` is found. See `:help fileformats` for more info.

Comment: The plugin sensible had a line: set fileformats+=mac. Upon commenting out that line, the problem is resolved. I don't know how this will affect anything else though. Thanks OregonTrail.
@Carpetsmoker: It doesn't work with unix,mac.

Answer (score 1):

You probably misset your `fileformats` options somehow to use `mac` end-of-line characters, which is a single `\r` (used only with pre-OSX-macs, OSX uses UNIX line endings).

You can check your setting by typing `:set fileformat`. The default should be set to `unix`.

Comment: OP states he's using `Ubuntu 12.04` is this still valid then? Ubuntu on a mac is still ubuntu, or?